# I would like to add a new line after printing an iterable in a for loop

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I am playing with hangman.  I loaded the word to guess into a list.  I am using a for loop to print the word with spaces and the end = "" so that they print across.  After all the letters print, I would like to move the cursor to a new line.  Is there an elegant way to do this?  Something that is part of the print function?

```
hidden_word = list(r.get_random_word().lower())
for letters in hidden_word:
    print(f"{letters} ", end="")
```

This prints the word in a line with a space between"

```
a b a c a d a b r a
```

But what is the best way to go to the next line after the print statement?

Just `print()`?

Or is there a switch or something that is part of the print function?

Comment: You want the words on one line, then a newline after? Yeah, just call `print()` after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Either add a `print` after the loop:

```
for letter in hidden_word:
    print(f"{letter} ", end="")
    # Or more clearly/with less work:
    print(letter, end=" ")
print()
```

Or avoid the loop and let [*-unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2921847/364696) plus `print`'s default of spaces between arguments do the work:

```
print(*hidden_word)
```

or use `str.join` to add the spaces between letter manually and print the single string that results:

```
print(' '.join(hidden_word))
```

Any of them work. Option 2 is the most concise/straight-forward, but probably also the least performant, but you're doing I/O, so the CPU costs are pretty meaningless anyway.

Comment: Oooo.  That's cool and very concise - researching now.

Comment: @CoolRunningASIC: I just added a link explaining `*`-unpacking in function calls. It's a hard one to search for (what with `*` not being particularly searchable).

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. Which is "best" is subjective; pick the one that you find simplest. Here are are a couple of common approaches:

```py
word = r.get_random_word().lower() # note that strings are iterable without being `list`s

# option 1 (your suggestion is fine, but it adds a trailing space)
for letter in word:
  print(letter, end=" ")
print()

# option 2 (print the last character differently)
for index, character in enumerate(word):
  if index == len(word) - 1:
    print(character)
  else:
    print(character, end=" ")

# option 3 (unpack each character into separate arguments, automatically separated by a single space)
print(*word)

# option 4 (explicitly join the characters with a space between each one)
print(" ".join(word))
```

Options 3 and 4 are clearly the most straightforward (and shortest), so they are preferred. An argument could be made that one is better than the other, but the difference is negligible in most cases.

Comment: YESS!! Researching

Answer (score -1):

To move the cursor to a new line after printing the word with spaces, you can simply use print() without any argument

```
hidden_word = list(r.get_random_word().lower())
for letter in hidden_word:

    print(f"{letter} ", end="")

# Move to the new line
print()
```

Comment: I have no idea why someone downvoted your answer. It's not a great answer but it is a reasonable answer. Keep contributing.